# storing results in function with loop - R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, output

I have a simple function `se <- 0.11 * (x^2) - 0.002 * x`. I want to generate two output variables `se.m` and `se.st`- each storing the results from 100 iterations with randomly renerated values for `x` at specific intervals:

```
se.m <- 0.11 * (x^2) - 0.002 * x      # if x[0,1]
```

or

```
se.st <- 0.11 * (x^2) - 0.002 * x     # if x(1,5]
```

I have written this code:

```
my.mat <- matrix(0,100,2)
x <- runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 5)

fuchs <- function(n){
   x.m <- runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1)
   x.st <- runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5)
  for(i in 1:n){
    print(x.m[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1))
    se.m <- 0.11 * (x.m^2) - 0.002 * x.m
    print(x.st[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5))
    se.st <- 0.11 * (x.st^2) - 0.002 * x.st
    }
  return(list(se.m, se.st))
}
fuchs(100)
```

How can I store the output in two columns? I have tried using the `matrix` command, but i get an error that the data is too long:

> my.mat<-matrix(my.mat, se.m)
>       Error in matrix(my.mat, se.m) : data is too long

Also the list command doesnt yield any output.

I am new to R as you can guess and would very much appriciate constructive comments/critique.

Comment: Another answer for your second question is simply: `cbind(se.m, se.st)` inside the function `fuchs()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The problem seems to be in indexing.

```
fuchs <- function(n){
x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL
  for(i in 1:n){
    print(x.m[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1))
    se.m[i] <- 0.11 * (x.m[i]^2) - 0.002 * x.m[i]
    print(x.st[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5))
    se.st[i] <- 0.11 * (x.st[i]^2) - 0.002 * x.st[i]
    }
  return(list(se.m, se.st))
}
fuchs(100)
```

In your original code, you set a single random numbers to variables `x.m` and `x.st` and then add additional values in the `for` cycle. In the last iteration, the equations work on the whole vector. Note that the `se.m` and `se.st` equations are identical:

> se.m <- 0.11 * (x^2) - 0.002 * x
>   se.st <- 0.11 * (x^2) - 0.002 * x

2) To output the result in a matrix, use code provided in comments by jogo, or use a `data.frame`. To better troubleshoot the code, I suggest returning also respective `x` values.

```
return(data.frame(x.m = x.m, se.m = se.m, x.st = x.st, se.st = se.st))
```

3) The `runif` function generates a number from the uniform distribution without the extreme values in your case. Text from the function help:

> `runif` will not generate either of the extreme values unless `max = min` or `max-min` is small compared to `min`, and in particular not for the default arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you loop. All functions you use are vectorized.

```
x.m <- runif(100, 0, 1)

#ensure 1 is not included
repeat {
  x.st <- runif(100, 1, 5)
  if (!any((x.st - 1) < .Machine$double.eps)) break
}

cbind(0.11 * (x.m^2) - 0.002 * x.m,
      0.11 * (x.st^2) - 0.002 * x.st)
```

The most difficult problem is sampling from an half-open interval. That leads to considerations of [floating point imprecision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1412059). As a result you'd need to exclude a fuzzy range around the interval limit. However, the probability that the lower interval limit is sampled is so low that it is practically zero. Thus, I wouldn't bother treating this case.